# why does 'if' and 'else' both get executed in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to detect collision in some cases, headshot, not headshot, missing the target.
Here is how I tried to achieve it:

```
  private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (interations.won && interations.currentlyPickedUpObject == null)
        {
           
            if (collision.collider == head) 
            {
                Debug.Log("HeadShot");
            }
            if (collision.collider == body || collision.collider == feet)
            {
                Debug.Log("Not a HeadShot");
            }
            else 
            {
                 Debug.Log("You've missed the target");
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue I'm facing is that the if and the else both get executed! shouldn't the else block get executed only if the if conditions are not met? why is this happening? I want to execute the else part only if the two conditions are false!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0aYX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  private bool hasCollided = false;
  private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (interations.won && interations.currentlyPickedUpObject == null && !hasCollided)
        {
            hasCollided = true;
            if (collision.collider == head) 
            {
                Debug.Log("HeadShot");
            }
            if (collision.collider == body || collision.collider == feet)
            {
                Debug.Log("Not a HeadShot");
            }
            else 
            {
                 Debug.Log("You've missed the target");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: great. no it is working

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the second `if` with `else if`, like this

```
else if (collision.collider == body || collision.collider == feet)
```

In your code, the `else` condition is linked only with the second `if` condition, and not the first `if`.

Comment: still giving me the same result

Answer (score 0):

They are both executed, because you got two if statements. Your first if statement is separate from the else, which in turn is tied to the second if.

Imagine collider is a head: your first if will be true. Then you go to the second if - the collider is neither body nor feet, and you go to the else, hence your code logs both *HeadShot*, and *You've missed the target*

To prevent that, you can use `else if`:

```
if (collision.collider == head) 
{
    Debug.Log("HeadShot");
}
else if (collision.collider == body || collision.collider == feet)
{
    Debug.Log("Not a HeadShot");
}
else 
{
     Debug.Log("You've missed the target");
}
```

as it will prevent the code from choosing multiple options.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried to do it as you suggested but it is still giving me the same result. The issue is that when I shot at the head I get a headshot because the bullet collided with the head, but after that, the bullet falls on the ground which triggers the else statement and prints "you've missed the target" even after the headshot was printed. I don't know how to prevent that from happening

Comment: Keep in mind that `OnCollisionEnter` is executed for every collider that your object comes in contact with. You should [destroy](https://docs.unity3d.com/2023.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) your bullet right after it processed the hit (or miss).